# need to load image into document after clicking next jquery

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, pageload

I want to load dynamic images (from server) in web page only after clicking next link. I dont want to increase the load time for page without knowing whether the user is interested to see those images or not. One image should be loaded, but the rest shouldnn't. If the user clicks next then only the rest of those images should load one by one.

I hope you guys got my point. This whole thing is about reducing the page load.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with google???

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter the `src` attribute of your images dynamically. For instance, in the handler for your 'next' button, you could do something like:

`$('#imageid').attr('src', 'http://myserver/mynextimage.jpg');`

jQuery's reference page for `attr` is here:

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Here's a fiddle showing how to loop through an array of images:

http://jsfiddle.net/33k2bh51/2/